# mysqli_transaction is not working or I misundersatnd

Tags: php, mysqli, transactions

MY **php** code for `mysqli transaction` is

```
<?php

/*db connection*/

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

mysqli_autocommit($conn, FALSE);

$insert1 = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO user(name,age,gender) VALUES('DEEPU', 24, 'male')");

$insert2 = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO user(name,age,gender2) VALUES('ANIL', 25, 'male')");

mysqli_commit($conn);

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

I know `mysqli transaction` is used for,  **If any operation within the transaction fails, the entire transaction will fail.**

**Problem:**

In my code second query is wrong, it uses `gender2` instead of `gender`. Since one query is failed, the entire transaction should fail. But here the first query execute and data is inserted in table. I expect no data will insert in table because the second query is fail.

Is any mistake in my code?? OR I totally misunderstand the point.

If I use

```
 mysqli_rollback($conn);
```

it brings to the `pre-transactional` state.

**NOTE**:I am using `innoDB` engine.

**What I need**

```
If both query is correct: data should insert.

If one is correct and other is wrong: no data will insert.
```

Pease help...Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`mysqli_query` returns true on succesful query. You can use this to commit if both queries succeed and else rollback if either fails.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

mysqli_autocommit($conn, FALSE);

$query1 = "INSERT INTO user(name,age,gender) VALUES('DEEPU', 24, 'male')";    
$query2 = "INSERT INTO user(name,age,gender2) VALUES('ANIL', 25, 'male')";

if(mysqli_query($conn, $query1) && mysqli_query($conn, $query2))
{
     mysqli_commit($conn);
}else
{
     mysqli_rollback($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```